# Making a fasta file from 2 different files

Tags: text-processing, files

I have 2 files `file1.seq` and `file2.seq`.

They look like these:

```
file1.seq
ACGGTGTGATG

file2.seq
CGTGATGATGT
```

I want to make one fasta file which would be like:

```
>file1.seq
ACGGTGTGATG
>file2.seq
CGTGATGATGT
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple for loop:

```
for f in file*.seq; do printf ">%s\n" "$f"; cat -- "$f"; done >newfile
```

- The `for` loop runs trough all files in the directory matching `file*.seq`.
- `printf` ptints the filename.
- and `cat` prints the contents of that file.
- `>newfile` redirecty everthing to the new file called `newfile`.

Or with `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==1{print ">"FILENAME}1' file*.seq
```

- `FNR==1` is the current record number in the file

  - `print ">"FILENAME` print the filename with a leading `>`
- `1` in all other cases print the line.